# Pygame GUI with two "screens"

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

is there any way to create a game were there are two background colors where one square is smaller than the other. In the background, I am thinking of being able to place buttons and so on. I have a game that works fine but I would like to develop it. As I have no  knowledge about how to do, I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame won't allow you to have more than one screen per application, if that is what you are asking. You can check the pyglet library for that: http://pyglet.org/ -

I can't figure out if you have any further doubts from your text, however - you will have to be more specific.

If it is about having a sub-section of the window as the action area of the game, and an outer margin where to to place controls, yes, that is just straightforward drawing with the provided calls.

Comment: Yes, exactly, more of a sub-section actually where I could place buttons for example.